# Android DownloadManager SSL Certificate Validation

Tags: android, ssl, android-download-manager

I'm in the process of making an app that fetches certain data from a server. For now it is just a test server with an untrusted certificate (will fix that soon).

Now I'm able to **disable** SSL Certif Validation to fetch data from the server myself (with an HTTPSUrlConnection) but if I want to download a certain file from there using the download manager then the download manager spits out the expected "CertPathValidatorException".

My question is can I somehow force the DM to disable SSL Certif Validation, similar to what I did to fetch data?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I'm able to disable SSL Certif Validation to fetch data from the server myself

Fortunately, people are starting to get sued for doing that in production apps.

> My question is can I somehow force the DM to disable SSL Certif Validation, similar to what I did to fetch data?

No.

Comment: I'm confused.  Either you can disable it and people are being sued for it or you can't.  You answer comes across contradictory.

Comment: @StephenM: The first quote and the first sentence of my answer refer to doing things outside of `DownloadManager`. The second quote and my corresponding "No" are for doing things with `DownloadManager`.